# Selenium cant find visualforce elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, visualforce

I can't get Selenium to locate any visualforce elements.

```
breed = driver.findElement(By.id("j_id0:SearchForm:j_id1:j_id2:j_id20:NativeBreed"));

breed = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input"));

breed = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id$='NativeBreed']"));
```

I have tried all of the above methods and it still wont find the element.

The apex code is as follows:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem ><!---------------------------Native Breed--------------------------->
      <apex:outputLabel value="Native Breed"/>
      <apex:inputCheckbox id="NativeBreed" value="{!searchBreed}" />
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

The generated Html is as follows:

```
<input id="j_id0:SearchForm:j_id1:j_id2:j_id20:NativeBreed" type="checkbox" name="j_id0:SearchForm:j_id1:j_id2:j_id20:NativeBreed">
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be the case or possible solutions?

edit: breed is a WebElement.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` you are using may be dynamic and so unable to find the element. Try using:

```
    breed = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,"NativeBreed")]"));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is this element the part of iFrame?